# How to create a short upper hyphen

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

How can I create a short hyphen, that connects two words in their upper part? The usual hyphen connects the words in their middle part. I tried to [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) it, but got only middle and bottom hyphens, not top hyphens.

Comment: What is the exact vertical position of your upper hyphen?

Comment: `\raisebox{.5ex}{-}`?

Comment: Can you perhaps show us somewhere is is used: while it's quite doable it seems rather odd.

Comment: @JosephWright this is the common way to write a hyphen in Hebrew

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi In that case I'd imagine it would be font-dependent and should be 'correct' in a Hebrew font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be many ways of doing what you asked for, the following is one of them.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\begin{document}

When used inside text.

top\raisebox{0.5em}{-}hyphen

\bigskip

And in math mode.

Inline equation,
$x\raisebox{0.25em}{-}y$

\medskip

Displayed equation,

\begin{equation}
  \sin(x\raisebox{0.25em}{-}y)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output,

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to make it work also in math mode? I tried to put it in math mode but got an error.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Glad to be of assistance. What kind of error are your getting in math mode? Please see my updated example. Could you please post your code and relevant error?

Answer (score 2):

The hyphen in Hebrew is the Unicode character "U+05BE HEBREW PUNCTUATION MAQAF".
Probably (there isn't a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for testing) you can get this hyphen directly or via `\hebmaqaf` or `\maqaf` with a Hebrew font.

Comment: This doesn't work, but probably because my document is not set up correctly for Hebrew, which I should ask in another question.. Thanks anyway.